# Dynamic text box list in Shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, lapply

I am trying to build an interface in Shiny where a user can dynamically build a decision tree. The problem I'm having is that when I try to dynamically generate the third layer in the tree I can't set a list of textInputs into a uiOutput. If you take a look at the code you can see I'm generating the level in the tree with a comma separated list from a corresponding text input. For the second layer there should be a separate text box for each node which also will have a comma separated list representing it's children. However when I try to generate the list of textInputs I get:

```
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

I understand that means I'm passing a list when I shouldn't be, but what I don't understand is why can't I pass a list of elements to uiOutput? I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help or suggestions on how to do this better would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Tree Builder"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        wellPanel(
          h4("Criteria"),
          textInput("txtDecison","Decision", placeholder = "Whatever you're trying to decide"),
          textInput("txtCriteria","Criteria", placeholder = "i.e.) criteria1,2, etc", value = "yip,yop")
        ),
        wellPanel(
          h4("Factors"),
          uiOutput("uiDynaFactors")
        ),
        wellPanel(
          h4("Alternatives"),
          textInput("txtBoxAlternatives", "Alternatives", placeholder = "i.e.) alternative 1, 2, etc")
        )
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         grVizOutput("xx")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  hdp=reactiveValues(tree=NULL,names=NULL,criteria=NULL,factors=NULL,alternatives=NULL,rendered=c(1))

  #create main tree
  observe({
    hdp$tree <- Node$new(input$txtDecison)

    nodeSplitter <- unlist(strsplit(input$txtCriteria, ","))
    for(v in nodeSplitter) {
      hdp$tree$AddChildNode(child=Node$new(v))
    }

    hdp$names <- hdp$tree$Get('name')

  })

 #HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
  observe({
    renderList <- list(1:length(unlist(strsplit(input$txtCriteria, ","))))

    output$uiDynaFactors <- renderUI({
      lapply(renderList,function(i){ 
        textInput(paste0('criteraFeature_',i), paste0('criteraFeature_',i))
      })
    })
  })

  output$xx=renderGrViz({
    grViz(DiagrammeR::generate_dot(ToDiagrammeRGraph(hdp$tree)),engine = "dot")
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(1:n)` creates a list with only one element: the vector `1:n`. So replace `renderList` with:

```
renderList <- 1:length(unlist(strsplit(input$txtCriteria, ",")))
```